# What is the process tree of that fork?

Tags: c, for-loop, process, treeview, fork

I'm just getting on with forks and this one got me really confused.
I have the script here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main () {
    int x=3;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<=2;i++){
        fork();
        x=x-1;
        printf(“process, %x\n”, x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the output here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1esiN.png)

Now, I tried to build the tree of processes with the added values of x, but it doesn't really feel good.
I thought the number of processes were 8 but they're 14 as the output says.
Does somebody can help me out here with the process tree!?
That's mine:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPtBJ.png)

Comment: You do not check return value of fork, so your code executes in both parent and the child. Is this what is confusing?

Comment: @Luca Scarpelli - You use wrong quotes.

Comment: I have to draw the tree of processes. In order to do that, I have to know how parent and child are working out here. I thought there would be only 8 processes at the end but the processes are 14 at the end. How they popped out? What are they doing? And yes, I checked the return value to help me understand how many processes are running.

Comment: It shouldn't make you feel good. fork() is a dysfunctional and inefficient function with limited usefulness. Pondering what it does might be a waste of time, when you could be learning useful multi-threading instead. If you study fork(), you might end up using it, where you should be using pthreads.

Comment: That's funny - _a dysfunctional function_.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct in that there are 8 processes - the original parent and 7 children. You just overlook that the number of printouts is not equal to the number of processes, since each parent continues after the fork and executes `printf` multiple times: original parent and first child 3 times each, two more children 2 times each, remaining four children only once; 3 + 3 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 14.

```
father x=3 i=0 fork x=2 print i=1 fork x=1 print i=2 fork x=0 print
               ch1                ch2                ch3
child1              x=2 print i=1 fork x=1 print i=2 fork x=0 print
                                  ch4                ch5
child2                                 x=1 print i=2 fork x=0 print
                                                     ch6
child3                                                    x=0 print
child4                                 x=1 print i=2 fork x=0 print
                                                     ch7
child5                                                    x=0 print
child6                                                    x=0 print
child7                                                    x=0 print
```

Comment: That was my bad on putting printf in the loop (lol). Thank you very much.

Comment: @LucaScarpelli Print the current pid with `getpid()` (unistd.h), it will help in your later explorations of `fork()`. Check `getpid` man page also.